# calculate a number without a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
if(ipadmenuheight < contentheight).css('top', '' + contentheight + 44 + 'px');
```

Let's say `contentheight=500`

then this code snippet returns `50044px`. How can it be a sum instead and return  `544px`?

Do I need to use a variable or can I do this inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parenthesis to sum both numbers.  If not, they will be appended as strings:

```
...css('top', (contentheight + 44) + 'px');
```

By the way, the first empty string `''` is not needed, so you could also do:

```
...css('top', contentheight + 44 + 'px');
```

Comment: Wouldn't `contentheight + 44 + 'px'` work just as well? I mean, the `'' +` is only causing trouble here.

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses to force numerical addition:

```
('top', '' + (contentheight + 44) + 'px');
```

or just take off the leading string.

```
('top', contentheight + 44 + 'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(ipadmenuheight < contentheight).css('top', '' + (contentheight + 44) + 'px');
```

or eventually

```
if(ipadmenuheight < contentheight).css('top', '' + (parseInt(contentheight, 10) + 44) + 'px');
```

if contentheight is a string.

Comment: You might want to use `parseInt(str, 10)` because otherwise you can get strange results like `parseInt('010') === 8`.